# How can i catch after completing async function(webkitgetasentry, file upload)?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, drag-and-drop, modal-dialog

I use function webkitgetasentry to upload files(include folder)
(drag and drop use)

below is my code

```
function drop(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    //call start modal (waiting file uploading...)
    var items = e.dataTransfer.items;
    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        var item = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
        if (item){
            callmyfunction(item);
        }
    }
    //start modal close
}
```

callmyfunction do file upload .

but this code run async.

so start modal close before callmyfunction all complete

how can i start modal close when callmyfunction all complete?

Comment: Pass a callback to callmyfunction and start modal close inside it

Comment: You can make it synchronous. One way to do that is to use `promises` or `generators`. OR the `async function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `callmyfunction` async function should accept a callback parameter, so that you can handle the modal closing there. Example:

```
function callmyfunction(item, cb) {
    // do uploading...
    // execute cb after upload
    cb();
}

function drop(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    //call start modal (waiting file uploading...)
    var items = e.dataTransfer.items;
    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        var item = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
        if (item){
            callmyfunction(item, function() { 
              // close modal
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Another option is to use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).